# C# ICustomTypeProvider in Code Behind

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am working on a WPF application and I have built a class that can be used in the XAML as so:

```
<MyControl.DataContext>
    <MyTypeProvider Name="AInstance">
        <MyObject Name="Object1"/>
        <MyObject Name="Object2"/>
    </MyTypeProvider>
 </MyControl.DataContext>
```

`MyTypeProvider` implements the `ICustomTypeProvider` interface and I have it correctly working so I am able to bind to `Object1` or `Object2`.

My question is two fold:

What's the best way to reference `Object1` or `Object2` in the code-behind?

What's the best way to add a new object to `MyTypeProvider` from code-behind?